# Variable Scope in C#, Java

Tags: c#, java, oop, scope

No, this is not my homework.
(Because there is a stack of answer sheets beside me, waiting to be marked.)

Q: If a local variable in a method has the same name as a variable in the main program, what will occur?
a) an error is generated
b) the variable in the main program is "hidden" until the method is finished executing
c) the variable in the main program will override the variable from the method
d) None of the above.

And the textbook answer is b, quite straightforward.

But on a second thought, is it really "hidden"?
As far as I know, in pure object-oriented languages like C# and Java,
we can always use

```
this.x
```

or

```
MainProgram.x
```

for static variables.

So my question is:
Can option b be considered true for C#? Why?

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: You seem to just be pointing out that the colloquial programmer's usage of 'hidden' here doesn't match the dictionary definition very well?  That is true of many things.

Comment: have a look on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I have never heard of shadowing. I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Check out [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/scope/), in particular: Simple names are not so simple [Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/02/simple-names-are-not-so-simple.aspx) [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/05/simple-names-are-not-so-simple-part-two.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the local variable `x` hides (or more precisely, *shadows* - thanks to @pst) the member variable `x` within the scope of that method / block. You can refer to the latter with its *qualified name* as `this.x`, to make life easier, but nevertheless the answer is correct. A (fully) qualified name is not scope-dependent anymore so it can't be hidden or shadowed.

Answer (score 2):

I refer you to section 3.7.1 of the C# 4 specification, the beginning of which I quote here for your convenience:

> The scope of an entity typically encompasses more program text than the declaration space of the entity. In particular, the scope of an entity may include declarations that introduce new declaration spaces containing entities of the same name. Such declarations cause the original entity to become **hidden**. Conversely, an entity is said to be **visible** when it is not **hidden**.

Correctly understanding this portion of the specification requires that you understand the difference between the *scope* of an entity and its *declaration space*. The **scope** is the region of program text in which the entity may be referred to by its unqualified name. The **declaration space** is the region of program text in which an entity's name is unique.

Read the rest of section 3.7.1 for the details.

I note also that the specified term is "hidden", though "shadowed" is also frequently used.

Comment: The C# specifications document bundled with .NET is an amazing source of information, and I have used it many times to shed light on things that seemed to defy logic. I wish more people would read it (no offence meant to the poster).